# Problems with Babel, TikZ, dot2texi, and Hebrew

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex, dot2texi

I've been trying to run pdflatex (with the -shell-escape flag of course) on the following code but got an error:
 ! Bad space factor (0).
  \@savsf

```
\documentclass[english, hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,tikz,options=-tmath] 
digraph G  
{
  iddqd -> idkfa -> iddqd;
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

The code works just fine if the first line is replaced with \documentclass[english]{article}. I've tried debugging it, but with no use. As mentioned [here](http://tex.aspcode.net/view/635399273629833626289578/tikz-and-babel-disagree-when-hebrew-is-loaded), the problem might be in TikZ and Babel, but I really doubt it is.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you tried loading TiKZ's `babel` library (for version PGF/TiKZ 3.0) or a workaround for the `babel` issue (for earlier versions)?

Comment: Why do you 'really doubt' that this is the same problem? Did you try the fix suggested there and find it didn't help?